# c++ nested template argument lookup failed

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider:

```
#include <vector>
template<int N> class B {};
template<int N> class A {};

template<int N, template<int> class T>
void doSomething(T<N> const& my_type) {
    //do sth...
}



int main() {
    B<42> b;
    doSomething(b); //OK

    std::vector<A<43>> vec_a;
    doSomething(vec_a); //FAIL: "no matching function for call to 'doSomething'
                        //      "candidate template ignored: could not match N against 'A<43>'"
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that instead of binding N with 43, the compiler tries to bind it with A<43> (which make sense since vec_a is of type `std::vector<A<43>>` and not of type `std::vector<A><43>` or something like that) and logically fails to do so.

What should I do ?
(compiler : clang++ 3.3)

Comment: Change the parameter of `doSomething` to `std::vector<T<N>>`!?

Comment: Of course this cannot work...

Comment: Depending on how well it's cloaked it may be impossible for the compiler to do what you want. This depends on what values that function may actually receive. If `std::vector` is your only concern then overload it for such.

Comment: @StoryTeller No because then I won't be able to use doSomething with A, and I want to be able to do so. I could of course just copy-paste for args of type A<N> and vector<A<N>> but it kind of defeats the purpose of templates

Comment: You'll have to overload the function, then.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you show us your approach to solving a problem, but not the problem itself - this kind of sounds like a design issue to me.

Comment: @nijansen aka the XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @nijansen OK I just edited to make it slighly more realistic. In fact, I want vector<A> and B for arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are several way to handle this but none is perfect.

The perfect way would be to use an alias i.e.

```
template<int N> using Vec_A = std::vector<A<N>>
Vec_A<43> vec_a;
doSomething(vec_a); //Error!
```

but alias is just a shorthand and seems to be replaced by the real type too soon. This is the case with clang++ at least, not with GCC. The standard seems to agree with clang (see Grizzly comment).

Another way is of course to overload (see Kerrek SB answer) but I find it ugly : for me, it defeats the point of using templates.

The last possibility, that I prefer here (but that I would not advice as a
default) is public inheritance:

```
template<int N> class Vec_A : public std::vector<A<N>> {};
```

It acts almost as an alias, except for the stronger typing (can't convert to a vector anymore) which is OK for me in this case.

Comment: Are you sure about the alias not working? I thought that this should actually work and at least [gcc](http://ideone.com/KLRtFv) seems to agree.

Comment: @Grizzly Yeah. In fact, I didn't understand why the compiler was complaining because I first got the error with this alias. Interesting that GCC understands though... I wonder what the standard says about that.

Comment: Disappointingly the standard does seem to agree with your statement in §14.5.7.2 [temp.alias]: "[ Note: An alias template name is never deduced.—end note ]".

Answer (score 0):

You could add a second overload that accepts vectors:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename A>
void doSomething(std::vector<T, A> const & v)
{
    doSomething(v[3]);
};
```

The body will call the other template, and assume the vector has at least four elements. Replace it with whichever logic you deem suitable.